# Create symlink in RPM

Tags: linux, puppet, rpm

I have a specific version of a software on Linux and I am packaging a .jar file (meant to upgrade the existing software) in an rpm and then trying to re-create a symlink to point to the latest version of the jar. I tried using `%post` and `%postun` to create and delete the symbolic link (in case it exists already), however this does not work. I have seen a few posts on the internet, but they did not work.

As a workaround, I tried to create the symlink in puppet. For this I used something like below:

```
if $version == ‘1.1'  {
    file { '/usr/share/prog/software.jar':
    ensure  => 'symlink',
    target  => '/usr/share/prog/java/software-1.1-bin.jar',
}
```

But even here, the new version jar is getting created, but not the symlink.

Please let me know if anybody has solved this problem before.

Below is the spec file that I had used:

```
%define base_install_dir %{_datadir}/prog

Name:cdplayer
Version:1.1
Epoch:1
Release:2el6
Source:cdplayer-1.1-bin.jar
BuildArch:noarch
%description    
%prep
%install
%{__mkdir} -p %{buildroot}%{base_install_dir}
%{__install} -D -m 755 %{SOURCE0} %{buildroot}%{base_install_dir}

%post
ln -s -f /usr/share/prog/cdplayer-1.1-bin.jar /usr/share/prog/cdplayer.jar
%postun
%{__rm} -f /usr/share/prog/cdplayer.jar
%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%dir %{base_install_dir}
%{base_install_dir}/*

%changelog
```

Comment: RPM is more flexible in this regard than Puppet.  If you show the spec-file you used, someone might offer advice.

Comment: I have added a simplified version of the spec

Comment: Just reading it, `/usr/share/prog` does not match `%{base_install_dir}` (it is outside that directory tree).

Comment: base_install_dir is actually defined as this:                                           %define base_install_dir %{_datadir}/prog. And __datadir points to /usr/share

Comment: Then you should update your example: `s/java/prog/`

Comment: Done. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: You can package a symlink in an RPM like normal. Just create it in `%{buildroot}` and list it in `%files`. No need to faff around with `%post` and `%postun`.

Comment: Why do you need to create a symlink to the latest version at install time? Will there ever be a case where two versions would be installed at the same time?

Comment: @EtanReisner: Thanks for your suggestion. I followed and it worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [symlink in particular directory using rpm spec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067277/symlink-in-particular-directory-using-rpm-spec)

Answer (score 4):

The given spec-file installs `cdplayer-1.1-bin.jar`, but links to `cdplayer-1.1.jar`.  Here is a diff showing changes I made to get it to work as intended:

```
--- foo.spec.orig   2015-11-16 20:34:48.000000000 -0500
+++ foo.spec        2015-11-16 20:44:08.017874483 -0500
@@ -1,21 +1,25 @@
 %define base_install_dir %{_datadir}/prog

+Summary: sample rpm spec-file
+License: unknown
 Name:cdplayer
 Version:1.1
 Epoch:1
 Release:2el6
-Source:cdplayer-1.1-bin.jar
+Source:%{name}-%{version}-bin.jar
 BuildArch:noarch
+%global actual %{name}-%{version}.jar
+%global linked %{name}.jar
 %description    
 %prep
 %install
 %{__mkdir} -p %{buildroot}%{base_install_dir}
-%{__install} -D -m 755 %{SOURCE0} %{buildroot}%{base_install_dir}
+%{__install} -D -m 755 %{SOURCE0} %{buildroot}%{base_install_dir}/%{actual}

 %post
-ln -s -f /usr/share/prog/cdplayer-1.1.jar /usr/share/prog/cdplayer.jar
+ln -s -f %{base_install_dir}/%{actual} %{base_install_dir}/%{linked}
 %postun
-%{__rm} -f /usr/share/prog/cdplayer.jar
+%{__rm} -f %{base_install_dir}/%{linked}
 %files
 %defattr(-,root,root,-)
 %dir %{base_install_dir}
```

There are a few problem areas in your spec-file to explore:

- there is a flaw in the way upgrades are handled which would appear if you used `yum` (see *[Own RPM package: Make symlink survive update/freshen](https://blog.hqcodeshop.fi/archives/96-Own-RPM-package-Make-symlink-survive-updatefreshen.html)* for example, which checks for the state before removing the link as a side-effect of package upgrade versus removal).
- you are using the `epoch` tag which requires care, but the question gives no clue about the steps you use regarding it for upgrades.
- if you install the package directly, for example, just changing the `epoch` value, you can end up with multiple copies of the same package.

Adding a `-v` option to the `rm` and `ln` commands would show you more clearly what the package does when you install it.

Comment: That is not the actual issue. This has been taken care of in my code and still does not create link.

Comment: Then something differs in your example from the actual - I did a test-install, and my modified spec-file worked as expected.